# trying to deploy an asp.net mvc application: are there alternatives to one-click publishing?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, windows, visual-studio, iis

I am trying to setup visual studio one-click publishing for an asp.net mvc application but am having some trouble getting one-click publishing properly configured. In the short-term, I just want to get the application on the server. Is there an alternative to one-click publishing? Something analogous to moving the proper files into the proper directories on an apache server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple options when using one-click publish. When choosing your publish method in the wizard you can use 'Web Deploy Package' which will write all the files to a zip file. This can then be moved to the server manually and published.

You also have the option of using FTP or going straight to a file system.

Here is a link that describes how to use the Web Deploy Package option:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465323.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not want remote publishing involves, one simple approach is to publish the site files to a folder and copy the files (FTP, SFTP, remote share, etc.) to the IIS web server. Apache does not execute the ASP.NET MVC code, so the Apache web server site must either redirect or proxy a connection to an IIS website. Regardless, you will need to configure the IIS website.

For the packaging, I suggest the following steps:

1. Open the Visual Studio solution
2. Right-click on the ASP.NET MVC project and choose "Publish..."
3. Change Publish Method to "File System"
4. Choose a folder to deploy the files, e.g. C:\temp\MyApplication. Note that you could publish the files directly using a network shared folder.

Here are the steps for IIS deployment:

1. Create a folder on the IIS web server that will contain your website, e.g. C:\inetpub\MySite.
2. Copy the publish output folder from your PC to the website folder. For example, copy the C:\temp\MyApplication folder to the IIS web server under C:\inetpub\MySite, so that the resulting folder will be C:\inetpub\MySite\MyApplication.
3. Open IIS Manager on the IIS Web Server.
4. Create a new website and point to your website folder, e.g. C:\inetpub\MySite. You could publish your app at the site level, but let's keep it clean as its own IIS Application.
5. Right-click on the new website and choose "Add Application". Choose the default ASP.NET v4.0 application pool for simplicity. There are many other docs that discuss how to create custom application pools.

You should be able to open the application in the IIS web server using the relative path "/MyApplication". There are quite a few different ways to deploy this content, so please take the above steps as a single suggestion. Hopefully this helps!